Who is the Kiratarupi Maharudra Rishi mentioned in the Dattatreya Vajra Kavacham?
The seer for the Dattatreya Vajra Kavacham is identified as 'Kirātarūpī Mahārudrṛṣiḥ'. This is inferred from the lines in the kavacham, as taken from the Himavath kanda of Sri Rudrayamala:

asya śrīdattātrēya vajrakavacha stōtramantrasya, kirātarūpī
mahārudrṛṣiḥ, anuṣṭup Chandaḥ, śrīdattātrēyō dēvatā, drāṃ bījam, āṃ
śaktiḥ, krauṃ kīlakam.

I am not very familiar with this rishi. Are there any chronicles about this rishi in any scriptures?
I only know about the Kirata form of Rudra, who battles with Arjuna and gives him the Pasupata weapon, along with imparting knowledge related to the weapon, as described in the Mahabharata:

After all those illustrious ascetics had gone away, that wielder of
the Pinaka and cleanser of all sins--the illustrious Hara--assuming
the form of a Kirata resplendent as a golden tree, and with a huge and
stalwart form like a second Meru, and taking up a hand some bow and a
number of arrows resembling snakes of virulent poison, and looking
like an embodiment of fire, came quickly down on the breast of
Himavat. And the handsome god of gods was accompanied by Uma in the
guise of a Kirata woman, and also by a swarm of merry spirits of
various forms and attire, and by thousands of women in the form and
attire of Kiratas.
......................
Bhava replied, 'O powerful one. I will give to thee that favourite
weapon of mine called the Pasuputa. O son of Pandu, thou art capable
of holding, hurling, and withdrawing it. Neither the chief himself of
the gods, nor Yama, nor the king of the Yakshas, nor Varuna, nor Vayu,
knoweth it. How could men know anything of it? But, O son of Pritha,
this weapon should not be hurled without adequate cause; for if hurled
at any foe of little might it may destroy the whole universe. In the
three worlds with all their mobile and immobile creatures, there is
none who is incapable of being slain by this weapon. And it may be
hurled by the mind, by the eye, by words, and by the bow.'"
Vaisampayana continued, "Hearing these words, the son of Pritha
purified himself. And approaching the lord of the universe with rapt
attention, he said, 'Instruct me!' Mahadeva then imparted unto that
best of Pandu's son the knowledge of that weapon looking like the
embodiment of Yama, together with all the mysteries about hurling and
withdrawing it.

The above information is taken from sections 39 and 40 of Kairata Parva of Vana Parva of the The Mahabharata.
Is this Kirata form of Rudra the same as the rishi mentioned in the Dattatreya Vajra Kavacham, or are they different altogether?
